# ASP.Net 5 Web API project missing several references after restore

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, dnx

I wanted to test out ASP.Net 5 with Visual Studio Code. I followed the instructions, and used the Yeoman generator to generate the Web API project. When done I ran a `dnu restore` (from inside Code), but I still get several errors related to missing references like `System.Object` and `System.Int32`. I understand the the DNX does not contain all the classes from the .Net framework, but this is generated code that I have not modified, so is there a possibility that this is a bug in the generator? I have run `dnu restore` several times, but it does not seem to fix anything. How can I fix this?

Here is my `project.json`

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Kestrel": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta5"
  },

  "commands": {
    "kestrel": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Kestrel --config hosting.ini",
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --config hosting.ini"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {},
    "dnxcore50": {}
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

Comment: You have to show us your "project.json" so we can determine what packages you have dependecies on.

Comment: What runtime are you using (you can find out by issuing `dnvm list`)? What feeds are configured in %AppData%/NuGet/NuGet.config?